# Why Electron Does Not Radiate In Bohr Orbits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics

Maxwell said that charged particles radiate when are in accelarating motion. I understand that $nλ=2πr$ must be fulfilled in order to create a sinusoidal standing wave and to satisfy the probability distribution problem, but I don't have any clue why electron doesn't radiate in this case !

Comment: You've tagged this question with 'quantization'. Think about that for a bit (specifically, photons as quanta). Does that help you to understand why the electron cannot radiate (once it's in the ground state)?

Comment: Hi Sam. This question has been asked already lots of times. I've linked the duplicate that seems most popular.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that electrons do _orbit_ the nucleus, Bhor's model is just approximately correct and you need Schroedinger's equation to really solve the problem of a single electron atom. And even that equation is only valid in the non-relativistic limits.

Comment: So nucleus is actually a node for electron(or the standing wave) ? like for f<sub>+3</sub> f<sub>-3</sub> if electron changes it bubble(like in Dale's image) nucleus will be on electron's path and that point will be a node or electrons cant change bubbles ? (I dont know if this question means anything or not :p I am trying to understand orbitals better . . .)